# Timeline slider does'nt always show up while listening to iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

I have noticed that, sometimes, the slider that represents the entire duration of a podcast and showing the current reading position (the one that you're able to move to go forward or backward rapidly) is not present in the UI. Sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not...

How can it be explained ? Is there a trick to make this slider hidden and shown ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider/speed controls as well as any lyrics, show notes, etc can be toggled on and off by simply tapping on the album cover/artwork once while in the iPod "Now Playing" screen

Comment: Thanks ! A lot of podcasts don't show significant differences between the 2 views (No cover, no description) so I didn't noticed that it was actually 2 different views !